# Golang json decoding fails on Array

Tags: json, go

I have an object like:

```
   a = [{
        "name": "rdj",
        "place": "meh",
        "meh" : ["bow", "blah"]
    }]
```

I defined a struct like:

```
type first struct {
    A []one
}

type one struct {
    Place string `json: "place"`
    Name string `json: "name"`
}
```

when I use the same in code like:

```
func main() {
    res, _ := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/sample/")
    defer res.Body.Close()
    var some first
    rd := json.NewDecoder(res.Body)
    err := rd.Decode(&some)
    errorme(err)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", some)
}
```

I get the below error:

```
panic: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type main.first
```

My understanding is:

`type first` defines the array and within that array is data structure defined in `type one`.

Comment: Can you please pose the body of the json that you're getting back as the body of `res`? Can't say whether or not your structs are defined correctly without seeing the raw json.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON is an array of objects. Use these types:

```
type one struct {   // Use struct for JSON object
  Place string `json: "place"`
  Name string `json: "name"`
}

...

var some []one   // Use slice for JSON array
rd := json.NewDecoder(res.Body)
err := rd.Decode(&some)
```

The the types in the question match this JSON structure:

```
{"A": [{
    "name": "rdj",
    "place": "meh",
    "meh" : ["bow", "blah"]
}]}
```

Comment: Probably on the money here though one can't be sure because the poster failed to include any actual json in their question!

Answer (score 1):

@rickydj,

1. If you need to have "first" as a separate type:

   `type first []one`
2. If you do not care about having "first" as a separate type, just cut down to 

   `var some []one`

   as @Mellow Marmot suggested above.